# CakePHP Dynamic Routes Configurations, is it POSSIBLE?? or just a DREAM?

Tags: php, cakephp, dynamic, routes

Im just wondering and curious about how to achieve dynamic routes configuration in cakephp, or as such that I can create two routes like so:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
```

without trigerring the error everytime a user go to my site. What I want to do is to set '/' as my default landing page when user is not logged in, but in other way if the user is logged in and Auth session is present, i would like to set the url to '/' but pointing to user's dashboard.

What I thought was importing session in routes.php will work but it was not the way I expected:

```
App::import('Session', 'Component');
$this->Session = new SessionComponent;

if($this->Session->check('Auth.User')) {
        Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
} else {
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, im sure many of us are waiting also for the answer.
Thank you very much in advance.
And wishing u a Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply switch this on the controller level. Point your `/` route to `UsersController::home`, in there do:

```
function home() {
    if ($this->Auth->user()) {
        $this->dashboard();
    } else {
        $this->login();
    }
}

function dashboard() {
    $this->render('dashboard');
}

function login() {
    $this->render('login');
}
```