# How to create dynamic routing depends on user authentication using CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

Normally my home page routing in CakePHP as below :

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
```

After login when user goes to home page, I redirect them as below :

```
function login (){
    ... ... ...
    if($this->Auth->user()){
         $this-> redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'dashboard'));
    }
    ... ... ...
}
```

Then browser shows url as  “/users/dashboard”. But I want to shows URL as “/” i.e. when logged users home page routing will be as below :

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'dashboard'));
```

Please share if you have any idea.

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but I think you can simply just connect your home to the dashbord. If the user is not logged in he will be redirected to login page by the auth component, anyway

Comment: I found an idea from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8628746/1787600)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the router as it was:

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));

Now in the log in method you have to use something like below:

1. Check whether the user is loogged in or not.
2. If not logged in then render the log in page.
3. If logged in then render the dashboard page.
4. Do what ever functionality inside the log in function.

   ```
   function login (){
     if($this->Auth->user('id')){
   if (!empty($this->data)) {
     //Do the login as per the information provided by user.
     //After log in redirect to the below
     $this->redirect('/');
   }
    //Do something.........
    $this->render('/users/login');
     }else{
      //Do something.........
      $this->render('/users/dashboard');
     }
   }
   ```